# Google App Engine - Custom forms during deployment

Tags: html, google-app-engine, deployment

We are trying to deploy a Google Web Application.   The applications runs fine on local machine but ran into an issue when deploying as Google App Engine.

```
-- Our Index File has this line
   <li><a href="validation_form">Data Validation</a></li>

-- Where validation_form is another HTML file in the same folder (WEB_iNF)

     Insert Data in the box below
    <form action="results/validation" method="post">  
        <textarea rows="50" cols="50" name = "inputJson" >
        </textarea> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>  
    </form>
```

on localhost when the link is clicked on the index page, the validation_form opens at localhost:8888/validation_form.

On Google App Engine, when I click the link, it downloads the validation_form to the local drive.

I was expecting this to show up at "myapp.appspot.com/validation_form".

Appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: So how would app engine know the content type of your file if you're html file is missing its extension? Are you serving through a servlet and setting the content type manually? The thing is: the link is working, but the servlet container does not know what to do with a file without extension. Simply adding the .html extension should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @konqi.   Not having the extension was a problem.   The program worked on localhost without the extension, thus I thought that the same would be true for GAE.

Comment: Glad i could help. I also created a proper answer from my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App engine does not know the content type of your file if your html file is missing its extension. This could work if you are serving through a servlet and setting the content type manually.

However: The link in you index file is working. Getting the form as download is proof of that. You get the download because the servlet container does not know what else to do with a file without extension.

Thus: Simply adding the .html extension should do the trick.